# Daily grep and output STATUS

Tags: linux, bash, date, scripting

I have a script thats running every hour from 05:00 - 00:00h and generates this log file:

2018-07-04 08:00:03 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 09:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 10:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 11:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 12:00:01 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 13:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 14:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 15:00:03 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 16:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 17:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 18:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 19:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 20:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 21:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 22:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-04 23:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-05 00:00:02 OK - reset script
2018-07-05 05:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-05 06:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-05 07:00:03 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-05 08:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-05 09:00:02 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-05 09:52:19 WARNING - no file today
2018-07-05 09:55:09 OK - file copied
2018-07-05 09:56:02 OK - reset script

If there is no file to copy it writes into the log "WARNING - no file today " and resets the script. If there is a file to copy today, it writes "OK - file copied" and resets the script.

I would need a script that outputs "WARNING - no file today" if file wasn´t created today or if a file was created the output "OK - file copied"...
So it checks in a log todays date and if a file was copied return OK status, else WARNING.

Any idea? :D

Comment: The log output you pasted has few to do with your question, do you mind showing us instead what attempts you made to setup a script that solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the existence of a file:

```
filename="/path/to/your/file.txt"
if [ -f $filename ]; then
    echo "OK - file copied"
else
    echo "WARNING - no file today"
fi
```

Comment: Tnx, but log file is containing records for every day. I need to check that only for todays date.

Comment: Does the name of the log file have the date embedded in it?  Could you provide an example filename?